# Convert a nvarchar with multiple numbers separated by commas to a set of numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been researching but I can't find the way to convert a stored procedure parameter that has a `nvarchar` like this:

```
'123456,123455,123454,123453,123452'
```

to

```
123456,123455,123454,123453,123452
```

for the `IN` clause that requires a number

```
@Co_Ordenes varchar(max) 
--code
WHERE T_OrdenAtencion.Co_OrdenAt in (@Co_Ordenes)
```

where `@co_ordenes` is a `nvarchar` but the `IN` must receive a list of numerics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically three choices:

- You can use dynamic SQL.
- You can call a `split()` function of some sort to split the string (there are various implementations on the web).
- You can use `like`.

(And there are more arcane possibilities in terms of using XML or recursive CTEs for the parsing.)

Here is a way to use `like`;

```
where ',' + @Co_Ordenes + ',' like '%,' + cast(T_OrdenAtencion.Co_OrdenAt as varchar(255)) + ',%'
```

However, this prevents the query from using an index on the `Co_OrdenAt` column.

Do you have the possibility of storing the list in some other format?  For instance, putting the list in in a temporary table would simplify the query and the resulting query could take advantage of available indexes?

Comment: The like clause worked perfect, is there any cons with that way? thanks you

Comment: @user3538146 . . . Yes.  The query will not use an index on the column.  If the table is small, this isn't a big deal.  If you have even thousands of rows, then you might want to use an index.

Comment: it will have like 100k rows, so should i change it? i ran the sp with a web api and it didnt give me any problem and it already has like +50k rows